# Can we use clr-dg-row inside the expandable row

Tags: vmware-clarity

In the example provided for expandable row in clarity, for MyDetailComponent , no `<clr-dg-row-detail>` tag is used in template. Is it okay to put any other tags like `<clr-dg-row> cell info here..</clr-dg-row>` without the `<clr-dg-row-detail>` in the MyDetailComponent  template?? I tried it and it works fine but wanted to check if it's the right way or not...

```js
@Component({
    selector: "my-detail",
    template: `
        <div [ clrLoading ]="loading">...</div>
    `
})
class MyDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() user: User;

    loading: boolean;
```

```html
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users">
  <-- Cells declarations -->
    <clr-dg-cell>...
    </clr-dg-cell>

    <my-detail *clrIfExpanded [user]="user" ngProjectAs="clr-dg-row-detail">
    </my-detail>
</clr-dg-row>
```

Comment: This does work in older versions of Clarity, but is not necessarily something we support. I suggest you do something more like putting your custom component inside of the detail.

`<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded><my-detail></my-detail></clr-dg-row-detail>`

Comment: Problem with putting inside clr-dg-row-detail is that it no longer gets rendered as datagrid-row and doesn't align properly with the datagrid columns